# How to allow an arbitrary group to mount a file system?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, mount

As far as I understood from the `mount` man page, by default only root is allowed to mount a filesystem. Filesystems with either the `user` or the `users` option can be mounted by any user. The `owner` and the `group` options allow only an owner and members of a group of a device file respectively to mount/unmount a filesystem.

Is there a way to permit only an arbitrary group to mount/unmount a filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Iain's answer works for any unix. However, in linux you can also specifically allow a group to mount a device.

- Make the device owned by the group you want to allow to mount it
- In /etc/fstab, use the option "group" instead of "user"

This is described in the man page for `mount(8)` (instead of the one for fstab, confusingly):

```
 FILESYSTEM INDEPENDENT MOUNT OPTIONS
 [...]
 group  Allow  an ordinary (i.e., non-root) user to mount the filesys-
          tem if one of his groups matches  the  group  of  the  device.
          This option implies the options nosuid and nodev (unless over-
          ridden  by  subsequent  options,  as  in   the   option   line
          group,dev,suid).
```

Here's an example, using the volume "vg_firefly-testmount". I am the user "jenny" with the group "jenny".

```
[jenny@firefly ~]$ ls -ld /dev/mapper/vg_firefly-testmount 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nov 26 10:43 /dev/mapper/vg_firefly-testmount -> ../dm-4
[jenny@firefly ~]$ ls -l /dev/dm-4
brw-rw---- 1 root jenny 253, 4 Nov 26 11:35 /dev/dm-4
[jenny@firefly ~]$ grep testmount /etc/fstab 
/dev/mapper/vg_firefly-testmount /testmount             ext4    group,noauto,rw    1 2
[jenny@firefly ~]$ mount /testmount
[jenny@firefly ~]$ mount | grep testmount
/dev/mapper/vg_firefly-testmount on /testmount type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=jenny)
```

Comment: How can I change a device group? Should I edit udev rules for this purpose? The device is a hard drive partition if it's important.

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Looks strange for me. The `/dev/mapper/vg_firefly-testmount` link is owned by the `root` group but you're able to mount it being logged in as `jenny`. Does `mount` follow the symlink and look at the group of the linked device? If so, how have you set the group of `/dev/dm-4` to `jenny`?

Comment: Mount follows the symlink, just like most other unix commands do, so it's the owner of the actual device that counts. I changed the group ownership of /dev/dm-4 by using "chgrp", just as I would for any other file or device.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do something like this is to use [sudo](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html)

- Create a group and add you privileged users to it.
- Create a script that does the mount/unmount action
- Ensure the script is executable but writeable only by root.
- Edit [sudoers](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) to allow the group to execute the script
- Profit